# Is there any way to read otp in ios automatically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to do sms verification through react native where an OTP will be sent to a provided number. It worked when I was doing it normally in react native following this example https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-android. But, the package only works for android, I want a solution which will work for both android and ios or ios. Is there any way?

Comment: Are you want to read otp from sms or you want to send sms???

Comment: I want to read otp from sms

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for an answer, starting iOS 12+, Apple introduced a new content input type `oneTimeCode`.

If you give the `textContentType='oneTimeCode'` to your text input, it will read the one time code from the message.

```
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Enter OTP"
      textContentType={'oneTimeCode'}
      value={input}
    />
```

Note, the message must contain either `Passcode` or `code` in the message and it shall start with <#>.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible to access text messages in ios. I too suffered the same issue and ended up making an android app for the same. Apple doesn't let any application to access anything outside its sandbox. Until it, itself provides an API for that.

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631168/automatic-otp-verification-in-ios. But I have no idea how to implement that!

Comment: As per the terms and conditions of Apple, it is not possible. I have done a lot of research. Apple is very strict with its policies.