# Read Message from SMS REACT NATIVE

Tags: android, ios, react-native, autocomplete

I am working on a log in process for a mobile app built in react-native... 
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T039NS2ED-FHARU61LH/image_from_ios.jpg

I want to have some sort of "From messages tab" that auto fills my passcode. I was wondering if anyone knew something that could lead me in the right direction about this.

Comment: Doing this kind of thing is going to be nearly impossible on newer Android apps, as access to SMS messages has been greatly reduced for privacy.  See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html

Comment: @GabeSechan Look at the screen shot, does ios do this automatically and it it simply not done automatically for android (the photo is from the app my team made from an ios device)

Answer (score 19):

For android you can try this npm

https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener

https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-sms-android

**IOS sms reading is not possible**  but i have read this stackoverflow answer
But I have no idea how to implement that!
 [Automatic OTP verification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631168/automatic-otp-verification-in-ios).

Comment: @SilambarasanRaman from iOS 12.0 onwards and from around RN v0.59.1 you can just use `<TextInput textContentType="oneTimeCode" />` and as soon as you get the sms keyboard will show the otp. Very easy :)

Comment: When I test this on android simulator my text input is not automatically updated I can only copy the value from SMS. Do you know what it could be? Is this only iOS feature? Is there something similar for android? @SagarKhatri

Comment: @mohwarf You need real device.

Answer (score 0):

for iOS, I've been struggling quite hard.

You have to put `textContentType="oneTimeCode"` and `keyboardType="numeric"` on your `TextInput`.
If you need to handle the code, also add a `onChangeText` prop to the TextInput

and FINALLY, the most important, if you don't see iOS poping up your code coming from SMS, check which message you're sending.
In my case, in French,

- `Veuillez saisir le code ${code} dans l'application` is working
- `Veuillez entrer ce code dans l'application : ${code}` is NOT working

I've been checking RN side for hours, and finally changing the SMS was the solution.