# what are the possible ways of reading Sms in React Native to auto populate the OTP in a textfield

Tags: react-native

What are the possible ways of reading SMS on receiving in react native, as I was trying to implement auto-populate the OTP in text field. as i was reading different sources i found out there is possibility to do it in android but not in ios.

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481400/read-message-from-sms-react-native

Comment: I think ios implementation is not possible for reading SMS with React Native.