# how to read and catch all sms in android database in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

is there any package to catch all sms data(sent and recived) in android sms database in react native?
I want to create sms manager application for android, but i cant find any package for this task in npm packages or github.
in your opinion,on this task ,are java and android studio the best choices?

Answer (score 1):

For android, you can try this Module

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-sms-listener

   import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener'

   SmsListener.addListener(message => {
   console.info(message)
   })

The contents of the message object will be Something Like This

```
{
  originatingAddress: string,
  body: string,
  timestamp: number
}
```

2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever

This Package is A Bit More Better Than The Above One

You Can Use It This Way

```
import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever';
 
// Get the phone number (first gif)
 _onPhoneNumberPressed = async () => {
  try {
    const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 };
 
// Get the SMS message (second gif)
_onSmsListenerPressed = async () => {
  try {
    const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
    if (registered) {
      SmsRetriever.addSmsListener(event => {
        console.log(event.message);
        SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
      }); 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};
```

IOS SMS reading is not possible but I have read this StackOverflow answer But I have no idea how to implement that! [Automatic OTP verification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631168/automatic-otp-verification-in-ios).