# UITextField not responding for verification codes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, autofill

I have a text field which I use in my app to enter verification codes from SMS,
I did all the required to make it capture the verification codes automatically but it doesn't!!
[image]

I did not use any codes for this
any advices ?

Comment: Does your SMS text follow the following format? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255825/5140621

Answer (score 0):

Set the `textContentType` property to `.oneTimeCode`. Example

```
myTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

[Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)