# SwiftUI iOS — get OTP code from SMS and save as variable automatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sms

In SwiftUI with iOS I know you can do the following to have the keyboard auto suggest an OTP that arrives by SMS:

```swift
TextField("OTP", text: $otp)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

In my app I'm using a custom number pad. Is it possible instead to fetch the OTP without using the keyboard so I can auto populate the custom fields myself automatically?

Comment: No, it is not possible.  Apps have no access to incoming messages

Answer (score -1):

Starting with iOS 12, the operating system automatically offers to substitute the incoming OTP code in the text field.

[Automatic OTP verification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631168/automatic-otp-verification-in-ios)