# Swift -How to put multiple characters in each individual SMS Otp UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I'm trying to input user emirates id in this format [image]

for this i try and follow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601324/428240

its working fine if i have one character but if you check the image, i want first textfield to show 3 characters, second to show 4 , third to show 7 and fourth textfield to show 1 character. and also if i try to remove character from textfield it should not remove all instead only remove one by one and then move to other once there is noting in textfield.

can any one help me with this. thanks in advance

```
protocol EmiratesIdTextFieldDelegate: class {
    func textFieldDidDelete()
}

import UIKit

class EmiratesIdTextField: UITextField {

weak var emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate: EmiratesIdTextFieldDelegate? // make sure to declare this as weak to prevent a memory leak/retain cycle

override func deleteBackward() {
    super.deleteBackward()
    emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate?.textFieldDidDelete()
}

// when a char is inside the textField this keeps the cursor to the right of it. If the user can get on the left side of the char and press the backspace the current char won't get deleted
override func closestPosition(to point: CGPoint) -> UITextPosition? {
    let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument
    let end = self.position(from: beginning, offset: self.text?.count ?? 0)
    return end
}

}
```

---

```
class PinViewController: UIViewController,EmiratesIdTextFieldDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: EmiratesIdTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: EmiratesIdTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3: EmiratesIdTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField4: EmiratesIdTextField!

var activeTextField = UITextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField1.delegate = self
    textField2.delegate = self
    textField3.delegate = self
    textField4.delegate = self

    textField1.emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate = self
    textField2.emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate = self
    textField3.emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate = self
    textField4.emiratesIdTextFieldDelegate = self

//  configureAnchors()

    textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    activeTextField = textField
}

func textFieldDidDelete() {

    if activeTextField == textField1 {
        print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField1")
        // do nothing
    }

    if activeTextField == textField2 {
        print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField2")
        textField2.isEnabled = false
        textField1.isEnabled = true
        textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField1.text = ""
    }

    if activeTextField == textField3 {
        print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField3")
        textField3.isEnabled = false
        textField2.isEnabled = true
        textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField2.text = ""
    }

    if activeTextField == textField4 {
        print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField4")
        textField4.isEnabled = false
        textField3.isEnabled = true
        textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField3.text = ""
    }
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let text = textField.text

    if let text = text {

        // 10. when the user enters something in the first textField it will automatically adjust to the next textField and in the process do some disabling and enabling. This will proceed until the last textField
        if (text.count < 1) && (string.count > 0) {

            if textField == textField1 {
                textField1.isEnabled = false
                textField2.isEnabled = true
                textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField2 {
                textField2.isEnabled = false
                textField3.isEnabled = true
                textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField3 {
                textField3.isEnabled = false
                textField4.isEnabled = true
                textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField4 {
                // do nothing
            }

            textField.text = string
            return false

        } // 11. if the user gets to the last textField and presses the back button everything above will get reversed
        else if (text.count >= 1) && (string.count == 0) {

            if textField == textField2 {
                textField2.isEnabled = false
                textField2.isEnabled = true
                textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
                textField1.text = ""
            }

            if textField == textField3 {
                textField3.isEnabled = false
                textField2.isEnabled = true
                textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
                textField2.text = ""
            }

            if textField == textField4 {
                textField4.isEnabled = false
                textField3.isEnabled = true
                textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
                textField3.text = ""
            }

            if textField == textField1 {
                // do nothing
            }

            textField.text = ""
            return false

        } // 12. after pressing the backButton and moving forward again you will have to do what's in step 10 all over again
        else if text.count >= 1 {

            if textField == textField1 {
                textField1.isEnabled = false
                textField2.isEnabled = true
                textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField2 {
                textField2.isEnabled = false
                textField3.isEnabled = true
                textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField3 {
                textField3.isEnabled = false
                textField4.isEnabled = true
                textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            if textField == textField4 {
                // do nothing
            }

            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you add some of your code.

Comment: code added. basically i didnot added because it is same as the thread mentioned in question,

Comment: Downvoted because your question doesn’t point out where you’re having problems or where you attempted to get these components to work. You slapped code from another answer in to this question and that’s it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601324/4833705). You can just copy and paste this into a file and run it to see how it works.

This one is different though because the OP wanted to know how Emirates uses their textFields using multiple digits in each textField. I don't know how their's works but this is how UberEats has their sms textFields working so I combined them both allowing multiple digits in each textField. You can't just randomly press a textField and select it. Using this you can only move forward and backwards. The ux is subjective but if Uber uses it the ux must be valid. I say it's similar because they also have a gray box covering the textField so I'm not sure what's going on behind it. This was the closest I could get.

First your going to have to subclass UITextField [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801258/4833705) to detect when the backspace button is pressed. When the back button is pressed there is logic pertaining to each textField inside step 11 that determines what text should be inside each textField.

Second your going to have to prevent the user from being able to select the left side of the cursor once a char is inside the textField [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919818/4833705). You override the method in the same subClass from the first step.

Third you need to detect which textField is currently active [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918882/4833705)

Fourth add an addTarget method to each textField to monitor as the user types. I added it to each textField and you will see them in step 8 at the bottom of viewDidLoad. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395000/4833705) to see how it works.

I'm doing everything programmatically so you can copy and paste the entire code into a project and run it

First create a subClass of UITextField and name it MyTextField (it's at the top of the file).

Second inside the class with the OTP textfields, set the class to use the UITextFieldDelegate and the MyTextFieldDelegate, then create a class property and name it activeTextField. When whichever textField becomes active inside textFieldDidBeginEditing you set the activeTextField to that. In viewDidLoad set all the textFields to use both delegates. The addTargets methods are in there also. You can just put them and there accompany delegates method in each `textField closure` for cleaner code. If you do that change each textField to begin with `lazy var` instead of `let`.

Make sure the First otpTextField is ENABLED and the second, third, and fourth otpTextFields are ALL initially DIASABLED

Everything is explained in the comments above the lines of code numbered from 1-12

```
import UIKit

protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: class {
    func textFieldDidDelete()
}

// 1. subclass UITextField and create protocol for it to know when the backButton is pressed
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    weak var myDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate? // make sure to declare this as weak to prevent a memory leak/retain cycle

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        myDelegate?.textFieldDidDelete()
    }

    // when a char is inside the textField this keeps the cursor to the right of it. If the user can get on the left side of the char and press the backspace the current char won't get deleted
    override func closestPosition(to point: CGPoint) -> UITextPosition? {
        let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument
        let end = self.position(from: beginning, offset: self.text?.count ?? 0)
        return end
    }
}

// 2. set the class to use BOTH Delegates
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MyTextFieldDelegate {

    let staticLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        label.text = "Enter the SMS code sent to your phone"
        return label
    }()

    // 3. make each textField of type MYTextField
    let otpTextField1: MyTextField = {
        let textField = MyTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        // **important this is initially ENABLED
        return textField
    }()

    let otpTextField2: MyTextField = {
        let textField = MyTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.isEnabled = false // **important this is initially DISABLED
        return textField
    }()

    let otpTextField3: MyTextField = {
        let textField = MyTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.isEnabled = false // **important this is initially DISABLED
        return textField
    }()

    let otpTextField4: MyTextField = {
        let textField = MyTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.isEnabled = false // **important this is initially DISABLED
        return textField
    }()

    // 4. create this property to know which textField is active. Set it in step 8 and use it in step 9
    var activeTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // 5. set the regular UItextField delegate to each textField
        otpTextField1.delegate = self
        otpTextField2.delegate = self
        otpTextField3.delegate = self
        otpTextField4.delegate = self

        // 6. set the subClassed textField delegate to each textField
        otpTextField1.myDelegate = self
        otpTextField2.myDelegate = self
        otpTextField3.myDelegate = self
        otpTextField4.myDelegate = self

        configureAnchors()

        // 7. once the screen appears show the keyboard
        otpTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()

        // 8. add this method to each textField's target action so it can be monitored while the user is typing
        otpTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(monitorTextFieldWhileTyping(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
        otpTextField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(monitorTextFieldWhileTyping(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
        otpTextField3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(monitorTextFieldWhileTyping(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
        otpTextField4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(monitorTextFieldWhileTyping(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        addBottomLayerTo(textField: otpTextField1)
        addBottomLayerTo(textField: otpTextField2)
        addBottomLayerTo(textField: otpTextField3)
        addBottomLayerTo(textField: otpTextField4)
    }

    // 9. when a textField is active set the activeTextField property to that textField
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        activeTextField = textField
    }

    // 10. when the backButton is pressed, the MyTextField delegate will get called. The activeTextField will let you know which textField the backButton was pressed in. Depending on the textField certain textFields will become enabled and disabled.
    func textFieldDidDelete() {

        if activeTextField == otpTextField1 {
            print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField1")
            // do nothing
        }

        if activeTextField == otpTextField2 {
            print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField2")
            otpTextField2.isEnabled = false
            otpTextField1.isEnabled = true
            otpTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if activeTextField == otpTextField3 {
            print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField3")
            otpTextField3.isEnabled = false
            otpTextField2.isEnabled = true
            otpTextField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if activeTextField == otpTextField4 {
            print("backButton was pressed in otpTextField4")
            otpTextField4.isEnabled = false
            otpTextField3.isEnabled = true
            otpTextField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    // 11. as the user types it will check which textField you are in and then once the text.count is what you want for that textField it will jump to the next textField
    @objc func monitorTextFieldWhileTyping(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if let text = textField.text {

            if text.count >= 1 {

                // otpTextField1
                if textField == otpTextField1 {

                    if let textInOtpTextField1 = otpTextField1.text {

                        if textInOtpTextField1.count == 3 {
                            otpTextField1.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField2.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField2.becomeFirstResponder()
                        }

                        // when the user presses the back button in textInOtpTextField2, now that they're back in textInOtpTextField1 if the conditional statement below is met this will execute
                        if textInOtpTextField1.count > 3 {

                            let firstThreeCharsInTextField1 = textInOtpTextField1.prefix(3)

                            let convertFirstThreeToString = String(firstThreeCharsInTextField1)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                                self?.otpTextField1.text = convertFirstThreeToString
                            }

                            otpTextField1.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField2.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField2.becomeFirstResponder()

                            let convertLastCharToString = String(textInOtpTextField1.last!)
                            otpTextField2.text = convertLastCharToString
                        }
                    }
                }

                // otpTextField2
                if textField == otpTextField2 {

                    if let textInOtpTextField2 = otpTextField2.text {

                        if textInOtpTextField2.count == 4 {

                            otpTextField2.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField3.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField3.becomeFirstResponder()
                        }

                        // when the user presses the back button in textInOtpTextField3, now that they're back in textInOtpTextField2 if the conditional statement below is met this will execute
                        if textInOtpTextField2.count > 4 {

                            let firstFourCharsInTextField2 = textInOtpTextField2.prefix(4)

                            let convertFirstFourToString = String(firstFourCharsInTextField2)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                                self?.otpTextField2.text = convertFirstFourToString
                            }

                            otpTextField2.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField3.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField3.becomeFirstResponder()

                            let convertLastCharToString = String(textInOtpTextField2.last!)
                            otpTextField3.text = convertLastCharToString
                        }
                    }
                }

                // otpTextField3
                if textField == otpTextField3 {

                    if let textInOtpTextField3 = otpTextField3.text {

                        if textInOtpTextField3.count == 7 {
                            otpTextField3.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField4.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField4.becomeFirstResponder()
                        }

                        // when the user presses the back button in textInOtpTextField4, now that they're back in textInOtpTextField4 if the conditional statement below is met this will execute
                        if textInOtpTextField3.count > 7 {

                            let firstSevenCharsInTextField3 = textInOtpTextField3.prefix(7)

                            let convertFirstSevenToString = String(firstSevenCharsInTextField3)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                                self?.otpTextField3.text = convertFirstSevenToString
                            }

                            otpTextField3.isEnabled = false
                            otpTextField4.isEnabled = true
                            otpTextField4.becomeFirstResponder()

                            let convertLastCharToString = String(textInOtpTextField3.last!)
                            otpTextField4.text = convertLastCharToString
                        }
                    }
                }

                if textField == otpTextField4 {
                    // do nothing
                }

                textField.text = text
            }
        }
    }

    // 12. Use this delegate method to limit the text in otpTextField4 so that it can only take 1 character
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if textField == otpTextField4 {

            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    // this adds a lightGray line at the bottom of the textField
    func addBottomLayerTo(textField: UITextField) {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.height - 2, width: textField.frame.width, height: 2)
        textField.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    func configureAnchors() {

        view.addSubview(staticLabel)

        view.addSubview(otpTextField1)
        view.addSubview(otpTextField2)
        view.addSubview(otpTextField3)
        view.addSubview(otpTextField4)

        let width = view.frame.width / 5

        staticLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        staticLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        staticLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        // textField 1
        otpTextField1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        otpTextField1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true

        // textField 2
        otpTextField2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField1.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField1.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        otpTextField2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true

        // textField 3
        otpTextField3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField2.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField1.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        otpTextField3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true

        // textField 4
        otpTextField4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField3.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        otpTextField4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        otpTextField4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otpTextField1.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        otpTextField4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi I spent a couple of hours working on this please upvote this and the other answer since they both work.

Comment: on clicking backspace its only removing the last textfield and not removing text for other textfield and not jumping back

Comment: I'm not sure what the snark remark is for. I'm the one helping you out. You can take the vote back, you still have time. Don't think your doing me any favors

Comment: this is not a snark remark , first take a look how you answer me. and comparing me with other persons.